# express-validator doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express-validator

I'm trying to use express-validator, but none of it's functions work. I'm not getting any errors either.

Example:

```
const check = require('express-validator/check').check;

router.post('/register', check('someRandomName').exists(), (req, res) => userController.register(req, res));
```

express-validator always allows it, even if I don't have `someRandomName` in the req.

I also tried using `body` instead of `check`, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `check` returns a [validation chain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator#validation-chain-api) which you suppose to validate result in your req after it using `validationResult`, so something like this:

```
const {check , validationResult}  = require('express-validator/check');

router.post('/register', check('someRandomName').exists(), (req, res) => {
       var err = validationResult(req);
       if (!err.isEmpty()) {
           console.log(err.mapped())
           // you stop here 
       } else {
           // you pass req and res on to your controller
       }
}
```

Comment: I feel like such a 'noob'. I could've read the documentation, but nooo

Comment: @Fusseldieb I only went and read the docs after I was stuck. lol